# Use one translation of Android app for several countries

Tags: android, localization

The default language of my android app is English. I also have a Russian translation, and I want to use it for several countries (Russia, Ukraine, Kazakhstan, etc.). Is there a way to do it other than putting a copy of the same file `strings.xml` to the corresponding folders (`values-ru`, `values-ua` etc.)?

Comment: I haven't found any other option except strings.xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Eclipse, on your project:

1. Configure Build Path...
2. Java Build Path > Link Source...
3. Browse... to the path of your shared resource, which I presume to be just res/values
4. Set Folder Name to be your localized folder, such as res/values-tl or res/values-ru
5. Ok both dialogs, and refresh your project folder.

You should be able to find the new linked folder in your Eclipse project, which should successfully refer to the same resource file.

Needless to say, all of the resource files in res/values will be linked, so be careful.

Answer (score 2):

I think you'll probably have to just copy the strings.xml file to the corresponding folder. As far as I know, that's the easiest way to do it.